# Where does authentication go in a webapi when using APIM, App Service, B2C, dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I am having trouble finding guidance on how I should approach authentication in my architecture. I am using Azure AD B2C for a dotnet core webapi app which is currently being deployed into Azure App Service. I am adding Azure API Management to the mix, does that change how I should approach authentication?

Right now I have this in the startup.cs:

```
   services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options => 
       {
           Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
           options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
       },
       options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });
```

Does Azure API Management change any of this?

Answer (score 0):

The auth approach doesn't affect when we are securing the api in azure apim.

In azure api management we are basically trying to create an inbound policy which will authenticate, and this is done using bearer tokens.

The same technology is used to secure the web api.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-api-management?tabs=app-reg-ga) which gives Indepth information on how to secure azure api management.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-api?tabs=csharpclient) which on securing the azure web api .